# Electron App & FFMpeg - Library not loaded

Tags: ffmpeg, electron

I've recently upgraded Electron to v0.37, and upon trying to start my app, I'm getting an error of the following.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libffmpeg.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework
Reason: image not found
```

I have ffmpeg installed on my machine via homebrew, which I installed with `brew install ffmpeg` .  I've tried uninstalling ffmpeg and reinstalling, but haven't had any luck.

I've noticed in more recent versions of Electron, since v0.36.8 they've 'Link with ffmpeg dynamically' according to the changelog.

I should note, I'm using ffmpeg in my electron app, and specifically, im utilizing the Fluent FFMpeg node library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg).

Has anyone come across this same issue?  Any idea on a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an known [issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/4765) in version 0.37. As a temporary workaround you can downgrade to version 0.36.